Are low resolutions possible in syslinux?
I am building an arcade machine with a 15KHz CRT and Batocera and I need to get syslinux to display in 320x240 because a CRT can only do up to 240p or 480i. Is it possible to do interlacing or 320x240 on syslinux?
I have tried
UI menu.c32
MENU RESOLUTION 320 240
...

and
MENU RESOLUTION 320 240
UI menu.c32
...

and with vesamenu.c32 too, but it doesn't update the resolution. It stays on the same resolution as the BIOS splash.

hm, why syslinux?

The SYSLINUX documentation says the menu.c32 is text-mode only, and in its source code, the set_resolution() function is defined to do nothing:
void set_resolution(int x, int y)
{
     (void)x;
     (void)y;
}

And in vesamenu.c32 the mode changing is implemented by calling a VESA VBIOS firmware routine, so it will only support the resolutions that your display adapter firmware will support. Basically, if you cannot get the mode you want in plain DOS via generic VESA support, you cannot get that mode in SYSLINUX either.
The function that actually does the work of setting the resolution within the vesamenu.c32 module is vesacon_set_mode(int x, int y). You can see it will just pass the resolution x and y values to the firmware, and offers no further parameters to configure.
The only exception seems to be if a i915-compatible Intel display adapter is used: in that case, there is an entire different branch of code - but even that relies on a list of modes provided by the firmware: it cannot program a new mode from scratch, like a full-fledged display driver of a modern OS might do.
If the attempt to set a resolution fails, the vesamenu.c32 keeps using the original display resolution.
